# Does this sentence sound weird in English?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

"Neptune’s natural light coming in through the top windows washed the station in baby blue hues."

I am alluding to the "washed with light" part. Does it sound like a legitimate literary expression or merely something a foreigner would write?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not outrageous.  If it's  your "style" and not jarringly inconsistent with the rest of the piece then it's OK.

Comment: What makes this feel awkward to my ears is the double clause (coming in... washed...). Consider rewording it to make it flow better and emphasize the part of the sentence you wish to be most prominent.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unremarkable use of *wash*. It derives from the use of the term in watercolor painting: a *wash* is a layer of color (typically applied across a large area) so highly diluted with water that it is semitransparent.

Comment: It's certainly *used* in watercolor painting that way. But you could also use *bathe* in the OP's sentence, a word I don't believe is used in watercolor painting. So I'm not convinced that's the correct etymological origin of this use of *wash*.